# Java z-base-32 encoding algorithm

Tags: java, base32

I'm searching for an implementation of [z-base-32 enc algo](http://zooko.com/repos/z-base-32/base32/DESIGN) in java, any suggestions?
(encoding and decoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I felt I had to give this a shot. I translated the C# implementation from [My Ten Pennies](http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog%3Abase-32-encoder) to Java, and [an example and source an be downloaded from here](https://github.com/WelcomWeb/zBase32j). It's not especially good looking code, but hey - it hopefully does it's work.

I haven't had time to test it thoroughly, but my short tests work fine.

Usage:

```
import se.welcomweb.utils.zbase32j;

public class TestZBase32J {

    public static void main(String ... args) {

        ZBase32j zbase = new ZBase32j();

        String message = "Hello, world!";
        String encoded = zbase.encode(message);
        System.out.println("Encoded: " + encoded);

        String decoded = zbase.decode(encoded);
        System.out.println("Decoded: " + decoded);

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately both the link you've provided returns an HTTP 404 or file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Chris - Thanks, updated link to a newly created repo instead.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't compare but it looks like the Base32 we use here. Here is the original code,

http://svn.savannah.gnu.org/svn/ccrtp/tags/release-ccrtp-1.7.0/contributions/ZRTP4J/src/gnu/java/zrtp/utils/Base32.java